# RefineryCMS How to add new menu in a admin pannel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

Can anyone guide me How to add new menu in a admin pannel  of refinerycms in ruby on rails application.

I just add one more tab. Is there anyway.?
[Admin pannel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoO4z.png)

Comment: Were you successful in making this happen?

Answer (score 0):

It's call an `Extension` you can create [generate a custom `Extension`](http://www.refinerycms.com/guides/generate-an-extension-to-use-your-mvcs) and it will appears as a menu in the admin panel.

Also, when generating an `Extension`, make sure you pass the necessary switch, e.g. `--i18n`, to avoid manual updating them later.

Comment: in that case, maybe you can try overriding the the `_site_bar` template

Comment: @Andy, is there any case that I can generate `Extension` in namespace? I mean namespace created in `vendor/extensions/projectname/ENGINE`? Could you please guide?